# Creating Inline Form, Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working in bootstrap and looking to create a form that has 2 rows and a submit button.  The first row should have 1 number field, where row 2 should have 3 number fields directly underneath the first row. Do I use the column and row class like below?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="number" class="col-xs-12">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="number" class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="number" class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="number" class="col-xs-3">
  </div>
</form>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I tested, it's OK. What is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some important parts.
The column classes should be added to `div` not `input`.
Also the columns should be wrapped in a `row` div.
Bootstrap has 12 column grid, so the sum of your columns should be 12.
That's why i changed `col-xs-3` to `col-xs-4` (3 columns of size 4).
Also you should add the class `form-control` to the inputs in order to give them the proper styling.
Take a look at this code:

```css
.my-margin {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form role="form">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-margin">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="number" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <input type="number" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <input type="number" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <input type="number" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also i suggest you read [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/) tutorial on the grid system in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The inline form can be done with **form-inline**

**Inline form**

Add .form-inline to your form (which doesn't have to be a ) for left-aligned and inline-block controls.

The solution by wazaap is also good.

[Bootstrap form-inline reference](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)

```css
.input-num {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
<form role="form">
 <div class="row col-xs-12 input-num">
     <input type="number" class="col-xs-12" placeholder="Enter a number"/>
 </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row form-inline grp-num">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter a number"/>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter a number"/>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter a number"/>
    </div>
 </div>
</form>
</div>
```